# javascript :not selector problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

As far as I understand I have the syntax here correct, but it's still all fading in? I must be doing something wrong is anyone able to help?

I'm simply trying to get .map_1 to fade in, but not .routemapred.

```
$('#listItem1').click(function(){
    $(".map_1:not('.routemapred')".fadeIn(500);
});
```

Comment: Do you mean routermapred should be visible while the rest fades in, or that routemapred should be hidden?

Comment: To clarify: map_1 should fade in, but routemapred should stay hidden. (they are both initially hidden) As it stands they are both fading in.

Comment: @KevinBoucher Ie it's not possible for a child to not be targeted? I must have misunderstood the :not selector. Is there no workaround? Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Just add .routemapred{display:none} and remove the :not part.

Comment: Don't put quotes inside `:not()`. Just `:not(.routemapred)`

Comment: You're also missing the `)` that matches `$(` on the second line.

Comment: @Barmar good spot! Unfortunately: $(".map_1:not(.routemapred)").fadeIn(500);
displays the same results

Comment: That selector matches `<div class="map_1">` but not `<div class="map_1 routemapred">`. So it should fade in the DIV you show in the HTML. What is it doing instead?

Comment: @Barmar I just want it to not fade in so that I can fade it in with another js line at another time. Perhaps it is another selector I'm looking for but :not(:has doesn't work either. They still both fade in when #listItem1 is clicked

Comment: @FINDarkside do you mean in the css? Both routemapred and map_1 are set to display:none before the click command

Comment: @Scott You sure? Because I just tried modifying the accepted answer to hide routemapred from css and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selector you used looks for a single element that has `class="map_1"` but doesn't have `class="routemapred"`. Your HTML has these classes on different elements, so you need to select them individually:

```js
$('#listItem1').click(function() {
  $(".map_1").fadeIn(500);
  $(".map_1 .routemapred").hide();
});
```

```css
.map_1 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="listItem1">Click</button>
<div class="map_1">
  This should fade in
  <div class="routemapred">
    This should not be visible
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed response. So sound and clear was it that I realised it must be something else amiss & indeed it was. My safari cache was glitching & a reinstall seems to have fixed the problem! Thank you again

Comment: Hiding routemapred from code is unecessary, you could just hide it from css like you did with map_1.

Comment: @FINDarkside I assume that in the full application this is conditional, sometimes it wants to display both.